# ESLint Vue multiword components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, eslint, vuejs3, vite

Is there a way to stop getting error from ESLint for single word **view** name in Vue3?

Every time I run ESLint, I get following message:

```sh
  1:1  error  Component name "About" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names
```

I currently have this setup:

file structure:

```
├── index.html
├── node_modules
├── npm
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   └── favicon.ico
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── App.vue
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── logo.svg
│   ├── components
│   │   └── Menu.vue
│   ├── env.d.ts
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── router
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── views
│       ├── About.vue
│       └── Home.vue
├── tsconfig.json
└── vite.config.ts
```

.eslintrc:

```json
{
    "root": true,
    "env": {
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "@vue/typescript/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2021
    },
    "rules": {}
}
```

package.json

```json
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,vue --ignore-path .gitignore ."
  },
...
}
```

Comment: Add the configuration you want into the `.eslintrc`? There's extensive guidance in the docs: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/. But the Vue style guide describes that one as "essential": https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-word-component-names-essential, which is why it's in that preset.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That was my initial idea, but as you say in "Components" it is essential. But from my understanding this does not include views as even vue-cli generates them with single-word names as you do not use them as tags in your code...

Comment: @Tomkys The only Component that is (should be) one word is App.vue - with the new update the generated components are also Multi-Word i bleieve

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Option 1: Disable globally

To disable the rule in all files (even those in `src/components`):

```js
// <projectRoot>/.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  ⋮
  rules: {
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0,
  },
}
```

### Option 2: `overrides` in ESLint config for `src/views/`

To disable the rule only for `src/views/**/*.vue`, specify an [`overrides` config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#how-do-overrides-work):

```js
// <projectRoot>/.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  ⋮
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['src/views/**/*.vue'],
      rules: {
        'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

***Note:** If using VS Code with the [ESLint Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint), restarting the ESLint Server (through [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)'s `>ESLint: Restart ESLint Server` command) or restarting the IDE might be needed to reload the configuration.*

### Option 3: Directory-level config for `src/views/`

It's also possible to disable the rule for `src/views/**/*.vue` with an [`.eslintrc.js` file in that directory](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#using-configuration-files):

```js
// <projectRoot>/src/views/.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For those still having this issue, add the following under rules in the `.eslintrc.js` file

```
rules: {
  ...
  'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0,
}
```

Comment: my eslint config rules were listed under `package.json`, and I had to *restart* VS Code for the change to take effect

Answer (score 6):

There's a simple solution. You need define your component name with more than one word as it states. Should be PascalCase as below;

> eg: AboutPage.vue

Answer (score 2):

Find a `vue.config.js` file in the project root directory, create one in the root directory if you don’t have one, write the code marked below, save it, and recompile it. The project will run normally

[image: vue.config.js]

Answer (score 2):

Change your component name from `About` to `AboutView`

This prevents conflicts with existing and future HTML elements, since all HTML elements are a single word.

**Bad**

```
<!-- in pre-compiled templates -->
<Item />

<!-- in in-DOM templates -->
<item></item>
```

---

**Good**

```
<!-- in pre-compiled templates -->
<TodoItem />

<!-- in in-DOM templates -->
<todo-item></todo-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just run this command and it will automatically fix the issue by removing the plugin itself:

```
npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint
```